# Release Keys/ KeyUp Selenium

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium

I have made a number of unit tests. In some of my tests I use shortcuts however sometimes these shortcuts get interrupted mid way through therefore I may have selected an Alt keyDown and then never got to do a KeyUp on it or release it which then causes my next test to mess up. I'm aware that the Ctrl, Alt and Shift button are toggling keys. Is there a way I can release all keys in my testInitalize section so I can release all keys before I run the next test?

At the moment I `keyDown` + `sendKeys` + `keyUp` as you can see in the below code

```
Actions action = new Actions(excelSession);
action.KeyDown(Keys.Alt).SendKeys(Keys.F4).KeyUp(Keys.Alt).B‌​uild().Perform();
```

Comment: @AluanHaddad How is this even helpful to the OP? Correcting the first sentence of his question? What he is doing could be a well full system test, you do not know from the code he provided?

Comment: In the future of development with visual studio 2017 and azure seminar Microsoft taught how to use Selenium with unit tests. Here is an example of what Microsoft are putting forward https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/01/27/getting-started-with-selenium-testing-in-a-continuous-integration-pipeline-with-visual-studio/

Comment: maybe do the keyUp on TestCleanup, but make sure before calling driver quits

Comment: The keyUp doesn't seem to release they keys for some reason

Comment: Maybe you can separate the keyUp and keyDown into 2 different actions.

Comment: I tried doing this at the beginning of my test to force a keyUp before I begin the test. `Actions action = new Actions(excelSession);
            action.KeyUp(Keys.Alt).Build().Perform();
            action.KeyUp(Keys.Shift).Build().Perform();
            action.KeyUp(Keys.Control).Build().Perform();` However it still seems to lock the keydown I have done from the previous test